# m.me links on Android do not work

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot, referer

I'm struggling to use a referer parameter on a Messenger chatbot m.me link.
I found a documentation mentionning that "The referral parameter is supported in the Messenger web client, as well as the Messenger app for iOS and Android version 92.0 and above". But when I look on Android version 92 does not exist ?
Any idea ? What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work well. Here are two examples in case you're not clear on what is being discussed; they work on pretty much all desktop and mobile platforms including *nix, Android, OSX, iOS, Windows.

1 m.me link with no referral (basic entry to Gabrielle Union Fans bot): https://m.me/gabriellefans

2 m.me link with referral (embedded news story deep link in bot)
http://m.me/Botworx?ref=beIFwSiQH4PpmC896ErcbTjjPzum45vqHXpWS1BgKme6Mk-pFikxQPWq5B5T8CIh3RhTltTdUrWlLRb2mI5RU4hIbx6krpmLAysmT96MlnWtoVBdaRCeJIZ6YmE5dtUlXyyWC9B_YQz5CCxs_fpQ7eN7IL_IdXGxMAxnIdYYuRxuCpU8H0prIIhXMFWfBAed